# Visual Studio 2015 - Bootstrap CSS stopped working on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2015

In the past few days I have been developing a unniversity project on Visual Studio by debugging on Google Chrome every single time.

Now I suspect that after updating my Windows 10 to the latest version - 1803 - something has stopped working while debugging on Chrome. The menus are no longer responsive, if I try to resize my page the content doesn't seem to go to the placed they used too and the text style has changed aswell.

**NOTE:** Debugging on Microsoft Edge appears to be working as expected.

Creating a new project with a bootstrap theme and debugging on Chrome gives the very same issue. Is there anything I can do to solve it?

Here's some screenshots of it debugging on Chrome and Edge.
[image: Google Chrome]

[image: Microsoft Edge]

Comment: Are you debugging javascript or C#?

Comment: @Phiter Debuggin in C#.